# How to place a <hr> relatively to a parent <div>?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to use a `<hr>` as an indicator of progress within a `<div>`. To this I expected that a combination of `position: absolute` and `top: ...px` would do the job:

```css
.container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <hr class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting the line to be 3/4 down from the top of the blue box:

[image]

Why is my positioning wrong?

---

**EDIT**: Through trial-and-error, I discovered that by adding a `width: 200px;` to the `hr` definition I can see the line, but I do not understand why so I am not making an answer of it. Specifically: what happens that the HR does not fill the width of the container on its own anymore

```css
.container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <hr class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not specific to hr, any absolute element is shrink-to-fit and hr has no content so 0 width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` property makes an element behave as if it was `display: block` in terms of space and position. Even if it was `display: inline` to begin with (like `<a>` or `<span>`). As for the `hr` element - it seems to have 0 `width` when it has `absolute` positioning. Reason: any absolute element is shrink-to-fit and hr has no content - thanks to Temani Afif's comment.

Another issue you will have, the container needs to be `position: relative` for the absolute positioning within it to be correct. That has a nice side effect that a percent of `width` will be of the width of the containing div. Perfect for progress bars.

```css
.container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.line {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <hr class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! *the container needs to be `position: relative` for the absolute positioning within it to be correct* → why is it so?

Comment: *The width property makes an element behave as if it was `display: block` in terms of space and position.* → I do not understand that. Using `width` forcefully switches to `display: block`? I do not think so, I must have misunderstood the sentence?

Comment: 1. so that the absolute position would still be relative to *something*. it might be implicitly the `<body>` but even then it is wise to make it `relative`.  2. there are some side effects when setting `width` to an `inline`  element.  here's a [read](https://css-tricks.com/exploring-the-complexities-of-width-and-height-in-css/) for example.

Comment: Thanks! well, this is more complicated than I thought :)